# how to use nested case and else in sql query

Tags: sql-server-2012, case

I have two tables from same database and one table from another database.The table from one database is `DCCT` from it, I want to retrieve two columns

**`logtime`**
and **`beam_current`**

The tables from another database is **`main_vacuum_analog`** and **`main_vacuum_status`**.On these two table I want to **apply following conditions**

**1)**`If` the **`value of columns st1_vs1_bag1_rb,st1_vs1_bag2_rb,st1_vs1_bag3_rb is 0`** **in main_vacuum_status** table

**`THEN`**

The value of **`st1_vs1_bag1_rb,st1_vs1_bag2_rb,st1_vs1_bag3_rb in main_vacuum_analog is set to OFF`**

**`ELSE`**

The value of **`st1_vs1_bag1_rb,st1_vs1_bag2_rb,st1_vs1_bag3_rb in main_vacuum_analog reamins as it is`**

**2)** When ever **`DCCT.logtime == main_vacuum_analog.logtime`** ,then the **`beam_current and logtime`** from DCCT table should also be **`retrieved`**

For the above condition I have to use **`Case and else`** in sql query.I tried my sql query code as-

```
select COALESCE(
  case when a.st1_vs1_bag1_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag1_rb end,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag2_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag2_rb end,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag3_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag3_rb end,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag4_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag4_rb end,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag5_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag5_rb end,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag6_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag6_rb end,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag7_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag7_rb end,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag8_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag8_rb **end as b.logtime,**
 from main_vacuum_status a, INDUS2_BDS.DBO.DCCT b,c.main_vacuum_analog
)
```

I'm not getting what to write at **`end as`** **in the sql query** ,its giving error message of incorrect syntax and moreover I doubt whether this is the code which can satisfy my condition.

Comment: When you say "is set to OFF" do you mean "OFF is returned from the select"? What do you mean "should also be retrieved"? SQL queries have a fixed number of columns; do you mean "return null if not true"?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add a select,

Like this: 
(
select
  case when a.st1_vs1_bag1_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag1_rb end
 from main_vacuum_status a, INDUS2_BDS.DBO.DCCT b,c.main_vacuum_analog
 )

Comment: In this way I have to apply 8 such conditions for **different bag** **values**.Moreover no column names will be displayed when I will do like this

Comment: if you want to use case method, you must set the column name unfortunately. Otherwise your column name set default like that; **select case when a.st1_vs1_bag1_rb='0' and a.logtime=b.logtime then 'OFF' else c.st1_vs1_bag1_rb end**

Comment: by default there will be no column name.How to use this select for multiple when and then??

Comment: Now showing error **Error converting data type varchar to real** when I just **change b.logtime to c.logtime**.Datatype of both logtime is same i.e datetime.

Comment: You should convert varchar to datetime. SELECT CONVERT(c.logtime, b.logtime, datetime_format). Original format is : SELECT CONVERT(DateTime, varchar, datetime_format)